# Python XML Element - Issue reading files with spaces in the file name/path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

Element Tree does not recognise spaces in the file name/path. For example, if the file name is "File with space.xml". It give the error No such file or directory but work fine when I remove the spaces

Below is the sample code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
inputFileName = "C:\\bla\\bla\\Documents\\File with space.xml"
tree = ET.parse(inputFileName)
```

Error message:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\bla\bla\Documents\File'

Is there anyway around this as I can't control the source file name?

Comment: Please share the "dir" or "ls" command output of directory where this file is there. Please also share the windows/linux environment.

Comment: Both should work, if the file is there: ` inputFileName = "D:\\Daten\\Programmieren\\stackoverflow\\File with space.xml" ` or ` inputFileName = r"D:/Daten/Programmieren/stackoverflow/File with space.xml" `

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a issue with Et.parse. Et parse accepts a filename or file object containing XML data. Please try to open the file with open() function and pass the file object to Et.parse. If you are unable to open it via open(), please check the file path, particularly the path separator or space in file path. Please note windows/linux have different path separator.